# How would you write an http to https redirect rule for web.config on IIS8 that would go directly to preferred domain with www.?

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, https, url-rewriting, web.config

I have a site that we just setup with SSL and have a redirect rule set up in web.config. We also use the `www.` as the preferred domain. The problem I have is I want to skip the middle step in the redirect.

What happens now is if you enter `http://example.com`, it redirects first to `https://example.com`, then again to `https://www.example.com`.

How can I setup the config to redirect straight from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`?

Here is the rule I am using now in my `web.config`.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="(.*)" /> 
        <conditions> 
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: _Aside:_ If you have any plans to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) then you will actually _need_ that middle step. ie. You should redirect to HTTPS _on the same host_ before redirecting to canonicalise the www/non-www.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer from another question that I tried and it seems to have worked. If there is a better solution, please provide your solution as well.

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" 
appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```